# updating a slice of dataframe from another dataframe accoding to the item number, Factor, and week number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Suppose you have dataframes look like that:

df1:

| Item Number | Model | Factor | 2/4/22 | 2/11/22 | 2/18/22 | 2/25/22 | 3/4/22 | 3/11/22 | 3/18/22 | 3/25/22 | 4/1/22 | 4/8/22 | 4/15/22 | 4/22/22 | 4/29/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | Sell out forecast | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | A | Inventory | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | A | Incoming | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 345 | B | Sell out forecast | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 345 | B | Inventory | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 345 | B | Incoming | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 678 | C | Sell out forecast | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 678 | C | Inventory | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 678 | C | Incoming | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| y-2 | Z | Sell out forecast | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| y-1 | Z | Inventory | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| y | Z | Incoming | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

df2:

| Item Number | Model | Factor | 1/7/22 | 1/14/22 | 1/21/22 | 1/28/22 | 2/4/22 | 2/11/22 | 2/18/22 | 2/25/22 | 3/4/22 | 3/11/22 | 3/18/22 | 3/25/22 | 4/1/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | Sells Forecast | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 345 | B | Sells Forecast | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

How can I updating the df1 data with df2 data, under the right factor row, model name and only apply to their common week (without changing other week's and model's  number)?

My expected output is like:

| Item Number | Model | Factor | 2/4/22 | 2/11/22 | 2/18/22 | 2/25/22 | 3/4/22 | 3/11/22 | 3/18/22 | 3/25/22 | 4/1/22 | 4/8/22 | 4/15/22 | 4/22/22 | 4/29/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | Sell out forecast | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | A | Inventory | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | A | Incoming | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 345 | B | Sell out forecast | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 345 | B | Inventory | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 345 | B | Incoming | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 678 | C | Sell out forecast | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 678 | C | Inventory | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 678 | C | Incoming | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| y-2 | Z | Sell out forecast | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| y-1 | Z | Inventory | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| y | Z | Incoming | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I tried to use iterrows to get each row in df1 and sliced the comon week cells out to match df2, but it doesn't work because the chained indexing won't let me change the orignial dataframe.

If anyone can help me out? I would really appricate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with a sudo-code like this:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():

    # Update Sell thru forecast

    for idx, r in df2.iterrows():

        if row["Factor"] == "Sell out Forecast" and row["Item Number"] == r["Item Number"]:

            df1.iloc[index,common_week_start:common_week_end+1]=r[common_week]


        break



    # Update Inventory

    # Update Incoming
```

But some pre-workouts need to do:

1. You need to for loop the `df1.column` and `df2.column` to get the common week list.
2. Set two variables,  `Common_week_start` and `Common_week_end`
3. Make sure the Factor name is identical (Lazy way, lol. Also, could use the regular expression)

Reason I was failed at the very beginning is that I used the `df.iloc[index][common_week]` the chain slicing creates a copy of the data, each loop only changes the copy values. Now I used`.iloc[index,column_start:column_end]`, it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with a [*MultiIndex*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html#pandas.MultiIndex) :

```
cols = ["Item Number", "Model", "Factor"]
df1 = df1.set_index(cols)

df1.update(df2.set_index(cols)) # returns `None`

df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Output :

```
print(df1)

   Item Number Model             Factor  2/4/22  2/11/22  2/18/22  2/25/22  3/4/22  3/11/22  3/18/22  3/25/22  4/1/22  4/8/22  4/15/22  4/22/22  4/29/22
0          123     A  Sell out forecast       5        6        7        8       9       10       11       12      13       0        0        0        0
1          123     A          Inventory       0        0        0        0       0        0        0        0       0       0        0        0        0
2          123     A           Incoming       0        0        0        0       0        0        0        0       0       0        0        0        0
3          345     B  Sell out forecast       2        2        2        2       2        2        2        2       2       0        0        0        0
4          345     B          Inventory       0        0        0        0       0        0        0        0       0       0        0        0        0
5          345     B           Incoming       0        0        0        0       0        0        0        0       0       0        0        0        0
6          678     C  Sell out forecast       0        0        0        0       0        0        0        0       0       0        0        0        0
7          678     C          Inventory       0        0        0        0       0        0        0        0       0       0        0        0        0
8          678     C           Incoming       0        0        0        0       0        0        0        0       0       0        0        0        0
```

Comment: **NB**: I removed the *four-to-last* lines in `df1` and  I fixed the typos in `Factor` of `df2`.